# Erlang web framework which can run as an OTP application

Tags: erlang, web-frameworks, erlang-otp

I am developing a small Erlang/OTP system and I need a web frontend for it.

As I don't want to write all that users, registration and db functionality myself, I am searching for a framework.

I would like to incorporate it into the system and be supervised by a supervisor to make all the components of the system fault-tolerant.

**Does there exist an Erlang-based web framework which can be used as a supervised part of an Erlang/OTP application?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link: http://buffered.io/posts/webmachine-erlydtl-and-riak-part-1/

He uses webmachine, Riak and Rebar to build an OTP application. I liked the way he separated the core server code from the web application code. What that means is that you can use any web framework that you like (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822518/current-state-of-erlang-web-development-frameworks-template-languages) to communicate with the core server in the back.

Comment: Thanks for the link mate. I'm still working on the 4th part of the series. Hope to have that done by the end of Q1 2012 (depending on time). The link to the whole series is http://buffered.io/series/web-development-with-erlang/ - more will be added over time. Thanks again!